# .Net Core SFTP integration tests in Bamboo on CentOS

Tags: .net-core, centos, continuous-integration, command-line-interface, bamboo

I'm writing integration tests for SFTP code, so my tests use an SFTP server library to spin up an SFTP server listening on a random port for each test case. Using .Net Core on Visual Studio 2019 for Mac, my tests all succeed. When I run on the Bamboo build server whose agents are running CentOS, I get the following error:

```
05:01:09.4224  ERROR Failed to connect to localhost System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (111): Connection refused
15-Aug-2020 05:01:10        at Renci.SshNet.Abstractions.SocketAbstraction.Connect(IPEndPoint remoteEndpoint, TimeSpan connectTimeout)
15-Aug-2020 05:01:10        at Renci.SshNet.Session.SocketConnect(String host, Int32 port)
15-Aug-2020 05:01:10        at Renci.SshNet.Session.Connect()
15-Aug-2020 05:01:10        at Renci.SshNet.BaseClient.CreateAndConnectSession()
15-Aug-2020 05:01:10        at Renci.SshNet.BaseClient.Connect()
```

The logs indicate that the SFTP server is starting up and binding to the random port correctly, so I'm not sure why the outbound connection to `localhost` would fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`localhost` didn't work, but `127.0.0.1` did work. Apparently the build agent doesn't have the `localhost` name configured.